# variable declared before cycle do not exist in cycle in c#

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I am using c#  and I have the flowing problem:
I decelerated the height variable before for cycle ant it says do not exist in the cycle.

In this part of the code I want the program to store all of the 3rd element of the "data" array except the first, so if the "data" array looks like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12... I want to get: 6,9,12...

```
static int[] tall()
{
    int[] data = database();//recalling an array filled with numbers
    int j = 0;
    int[] height;
    for (int i = 6; i < data.Length; )
    {
        i = i + 3;
        j++;
        height[j] = data[i];//Use of unassigned local variable 'height'
    }
    return height;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about *cycle* but you have to initialize your array like `int[] height = new int[data.Length];` or `int[] height = new int[data.Length - 6];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tells you what the problem is. Unfortunately, it does not tell you how to fix it.

You need to assign `height` to an array of `int`, but first you need to figure out its length. You can compute the length by subtracting the index of the initial data point (i.e. 6) from the length, dividing the result by 3, and adding 1. This can be simplified to `(length-3)/3`:

```
int[] height = new int[(data.Length-3)/3];
```

This assumes that `data.Length` is at least 4, otherwise the count is going to be negative.

You should also move the adjustment of indexes to a point after the assignment, or better yet, to the header of the loop:

```
// Start i at 5, because array indexes are zero-based.
for (int i = 5; i < data.Length; i+=3, j++) {
    height[j] = data[i];
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Vcj5Qp)